# Host Parameter While Creating a User in Rackspace Cloud Database Instance

Tags: python, mysql, database, cloud, rackspace-cloud

Rackspace has added the feature to select certain cloud servers (as hosts) while creating a user in a cloud database instance. This allows the specified user to be accessed, only from those cloud servers.

So I would like to know whether there is an API available in pyrax(python SDK for Rackspace APIs) to accomplish this or not.

If possible, then how to pass multiple cloud server IPs using the API.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I released version 1.6.1 of pyrax a few days ago that adds support for the 'host' parameter for users, as well as for Cloud Database backups.

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional 'host' parameter you can pass when creating a Cloud Database user according to the [Rackspace documentation](http://docs.rackspace.com/cdb/api/v1.0/cdb-devguide/content/POST_createUser__version___accountId__instances__instanceId__users_.html).

However, after looking at the [Pyrax code for Cloud Databases](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/pyrax/clouddatabases.py#L298), it doesn't look like that functionality is implemented yet.

Comment: There's probably a way to use the raw API alongside pyrax. We should see how to add this feature and possibly make a pull request.